# JFET impact-ionization current

Tags: current, jfet

Can someone explain me what impact-ionization current means and when does it happen? As far as I'm concerned, it's about gate current leakage when operated with high Vds and Id. If I'm right, why does this happen? What are the consequences of this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How familiar are you with semiconductor physics? You might want to look up the term "avalanche breakdown", as it's the region of operation where impact ionization occurs.

Comment: The only avalanche breakdown that I know for a JFET occures when Vds gets over a certain voltage which cause a huge amount of current to flow from the drain to source.

Comment: Your noise floor degrades. Check into the thread "simplistic njfet riaa" on diyAudio; they discuss the problems (audible problems) with too high a Vds.